# Any way to clear a databound listbox?

Tags: vb.net, listboxitem

I have a listbox that is populated at form.load
The items in the listbox change depending on a selected item in a combobox.

I want to add a radio button that when chosen, the listbox items that are shown are all removed. Clear doesn't work I think since the listbox is databound. Is there a simple way of removing these items?

Comment: Unbind it from the data source and then clear if needed?

Comment: add/remove items from the data source

Comment: @Tony Hinkle, I have 3 radio buttons (Add, Update, Delete) I want the listbox to populate from the DB whenever I click on Update or Delete, but I want it to clear on Add. I don't want the data actually removed from the DB as I have a separate button to commit those changes.

Comment: OK--so in the OnSelect handler, check to see if the Add option was selected, and if so, unbind the data object from the listbox and clear it.

Comment: I can write code and test it this evening, perhaps, if you still haven't gotten it by then.

Comment: @Tony Hinkle, ok, so I actually created a sub that runs the initial data collection on form.load, and I fire it off so that when it runs that logic, it checks on an IF statement if the Add button is checked (which assigns the datasource to null) or not (which retrieves the data as normal) Thanks Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this, depending on where you are in the code and how the program flows.

1. Before the data source is bound to the list box, check to see if the specified radio button is selected, and if it is, don't bind the data source.
2. In the event handler for the CheckChanged event of the radio button, check to see if it is checked, and then unbind the data source from the listbox, and if necessary then do a `listbox.clear()`.

Comment: this ended up working perfectly by checking for the add button, and not binding the data source.